# Determining where to restore element after removal and subsequent change of containing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, merge

I have an array of elements. Some element is removed. Then the array is changed in some way, this can be removal or addition of elements, moving elements around in the array or a combination of these.

Now I want to put the removed element back so that it's as close to its original neighbors as possible. Imagine these elements to be sentences in a text and the user can choose to undo the removal of a sentence they removed a while ago. (This is not the actual use case but equivalent)

I had the idea to save the list of element ids (each element has a uuid) at the removal of the element and then use that in some way to restore the element to its original position *respecting the context of the array*. Just looking at the previous element doesn't work since it would be messed up if that previous element was deleted or moved in the meantime.

Looking at the average movement of the elements that were around the removed element doesn't seem like a good idea either since that would cause it to be at some random position between them, and not at a particularly significant one.

Edit: apparently that was not a clear enough description of what I mean by "optimal", here are some examples to illustrate what I mean:

```
//start
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

//removal of 4
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

//array changed in some way...
[1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8]

//should yield:
[1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8]

//more examples: (changed array, array with element added back)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[5, 6], [4, 5, 6]
[6, 5], [4, 6, 5]
[6, 5, 3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You should provide your code if you want help with this

Comment: as in an example of possible states in the process? I'm not looking for implementation, just design of the algorithm...

Comment: You can't have an algorithm until you've **defined** your goal.  Your posting fails to specify "optimal" within your paradigm.  As such, this strikes me as a discussion in NLP and semantics, rather than an algorithm request.

Comment: I've added illustrative examples and clarified the text. Hopefully that is sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a list of elements and a target element. For each element, we can calculate the offset to the target element (the predecessor has `-1`, the successor has `+1` and so on). We could restrict this to a local neighborhood if we want.

Now we have a modified list where the target element is not present and the other elements are in a different order (or disappeared). But we still know the offsets. Therefore, each element can vote for a new place of the target element. If all votes agree, we are good. But this will not happen in general. So what can we do.

In essence, this is a minimization problem, where we want to pick a new position for the target element such that we minimize some error. We can measure the error very differently. We want the new position to be close to all the votes, so some form of summed difference seems to make sense.

Your proposal to use the average vote position is equal to minimizing the L2 error of differences. As you found, this is very sensitive to outliers (i.e., single elements that moved very far).

A more robust option would be L1 minimization. The solution of that is the median of the vote positions. But a similar effect could still happen. But you might want to try it anyway.

I would argue for L0 minimization. I.e., take the position that most other elements agree on (count how many elements vote for each position and pick the maximum). If there are multiple such positions, you can then take L1 and L2 errors into account.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually helpful.